# How to plot the hazard function of Birnbaum-Saunders distribution in R?

Tags: r

I am working with a distribution that is very similar to Birnbaum-Saunders distribution, but I don't know how to plot its hazard function in R. The hazard function of Birnbaum-Saunders distribution is,

[image]

, where [image: epsilon(t) = t^(1/2)-t^(-1/2)] with *t*>0,\alpha>0.
I have tried to plot the hazard function $h(t;\alpha)$ using the function plot() in R but failed to create a form for the denominator part. The denominator is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. Is anyone know how to deal with this kind of function when we are plotting in R?

Comment: Can you please describe what you did so far and explain where you have concrete issues? Also, it would be nice if you provide complete notation (e.g. $\epsilon(t)=...$). I think combining [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_ratio), using the package [extraDistr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extraDistr/index.html), and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947308005434) should help.

Comment: Further, search for hazard + plot + R.

Comment: Often search engines don't do as well with `R` as they do with `"R"` (quotes intended); it's not foolproof, but for google at least it *requires* and and often produces more relevant results. I often include `"CRAN"` in my searches, though that does limit from non-CRAN packages.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anakha K K! This question is not well-formed for StackOverflow. Generally questions need to be concrete, usually with actual code attemped, sample data to support it, and actual-vs-expected output. Further, asking us to recommend packages is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), though I understand there are few sites that provide the exposure you seek. Please expand your research and attempt to code this. One can peruse the CRAN Task Views, the one on [Probability Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) might be useful.

Comment: However, just search for ["CRAN" "Birnbaum" "hazard"](https://www.google.com/search?q="CRAN"+"Birnbaum"+"hazard"), one of the first links is the [`bssn`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bssn/) package, perhaps it can be of some utility. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The more detail you can show (e.g. your code for computing the numerator), the more people will be encouraged to help you with the parts you can't do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just stuck on the denominator in this expression, it will help to know that the cumulative distribution of the standard normal ($\Phi$) is computed by the `pnorm()` function in R. So:

```r
eps <- function(t) { s <- sqrt(t); s - 1/s }
pnorm(-eps(t)/alpha)
```